# Transform geographic coordinate DSM in decimal coordinate in python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a data frame with two columns, longitude and latitude in DSM format, and I would like to transform them into decimal coordinates in a tuple.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple

def convert_to_degrees(lat: float, lon: float) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    
    lat_deg, lat_min, lat_sec = [float(x) for x in str(lat).split("'")]
    lon_deg, lon_min, lon_sec = [float(x) for x in str(lon).split("'")]
    
    lat_dd = lat_deg + lat_min/60 + lat_sec/3600
    lon_dd = lon_deg + lon_min/60 + lon_sec/3600
    
    return (lat_dd, lon_dd)

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'latitude': ["2°45'49.0", "8°31'18.8", "8°41'18.8"],
    'longitude': ["47°29'51.5", "46°44'47.8", "45°42'47.8"]
})


df['lat_lon_dd'] = df.apply(lambda row: convert_to_degrees(row['latitude'], row['longitude']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

but my code retorn the error: could not convert string to float: "45'49."

the expected is a new column with:
(2.763611111111111, 47.49763888888889)
(8.52188888888889, 46.74661111111111)
(8.688555555555555, 45.71327777777778)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting -- it should've thrown an error for trying to float() with the degree symbol first. You'll have to split by the degree as well as the single quote / tick. You can either use the unicode `'\u00b0'` or `char(176)`:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple

def convert_to_degrees(lat: str, lon: str) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    split_lat = lat.split(chr(176))
    lat_deg = split_lat[0]
    lat_min, lat_sec = split_lat[1].split("'")
    lat_coord_strs = [lat_deg, lat_min, lat_sec]
    lat_coord = [float(x) for x in lat_coord_strs]
    lat_deg, lat_min, lat_sec = lat_coord

    split_lon = lon.split(chr(176))
    lon_deg = split_lon[0]
    lon_min, lon_sec = split_lon[1].split("'")
    lon_coord_strs = [lon_deg, lon_min, lon_sec]
    lon_coord = [float(x) for x in lon_coord_strs]
    lon_deg, lon_min, lon_sec = lon_coord

    lat_dd = lat_deg + lat_min / 60 + lat_sec / 3600
    lon_dd = lon_deg + lon_min / 60 + lon_sec / 3600

    return lat_dd, lon_dd


# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'latitude': ["2°45'49.0", "8°31'18.8", "8°41'18.8"],
    'longitude': ["47°29'51.5", "46°44'47.8", "45°42'47.8"]
})

df['lat_lon_dd'] = df.apply(lambda row: convert_to_degrees(row['latitude'], row['longitude']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

and this should print:

```
    latitude   longitude                               lat_lon_dd
0  2°45'49.0  47°29'51.5  (2.763611111111111, 47.497638888888886)
1  8°31'18.8  46°44'47.8   (8.52188888888889, 46.746611111111115)
2  8°41'18.8  45°42'47.8   (8.688555555555556, 45.71327777777778)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, when I apply this code in my dataset the return is: 'float' object has no attribute 'split', and the  Collaboratory underline split_lat = lat.split(chr(176))

Comment: I am a bit confused--why did you specify the type of your parameters (lat and lon) as floats when you are giving string arguments from the DF? It sounds like it's throwing an error because you can't split() a float but you defined the parameters as floats even though you pass strings -- did you change this part: (lat: str, lon: str) ?